# clickhouse create table Exception: Aggregate function minState(origin_user) is found in wrong place in query

Tags: clickhouse

```
CREATE TABLE user_dwd.user_tag_bitmap_local 
(
    `tag` String,
    `tag_item` String,
    `p_day` Date,
    `origin_user` UInt64,
    `users` AggregateFunction(min, UInt64) MATERIALIZED minState(origin_user)
)
ENGINE = AggregatingMergeTree()
PARTITION BY toYYYYMMDD(p_day)
ORDER BY (tag, tag_item)
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192;
```

when running sql to create table, show error:

**[2021-10-17 12:05:28] Code: 184, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Aggregate function minState(origin_user) is found in wrong place in query: While processing minState(origin_user) AS users_tmp_alter9508717652815860223: default expression and column type are incompatible. (version 21.8.4.51 (official build))**

how to solve the error?

Answer (score 0):

minState is an aggregating function, you cannot use it like this (it is for queries with a groupby section).
To solve it you can use `MATERIALIZED initializeAggregation...` or `MATERIALIZED arrayReduce(minState...`

But actually you don't need the second column.
You are looking for SimpleAggregateFunction:

https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/data-types/simpleaggregatefunction/

```sql
CREATE TABLE user_dwd.user_tag_bitmap_local 
(
    `tag` String,
    `tag_item` String,
    `p_day` Date,
    `origin_user` SimpleAggregateFunction(min, UInt64) ---<<<-----
)
ENGINE = AggregatingMergeTree()
PARTITION BY toYYYYMMDD(p_day)
ORDER BY (tag, tag_item)
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192;
```

---

https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/other-functions/#initializeaggregation

```sql
CREATE TABLE user_tag_bitmap_local
(
    `tag` String,
    `tag_item` String,
    `p_day` Date,
    `origin_user` UInt64,
    `users` AggregateFunction(min, UInt64) MATERIALIZED initializeAggregation('minState', origin_user)
)
ENGINE = AggregatingMergeTree
PARTITION BY toYYYYMMDD(p_day)
ORDER BY (tag, tag_item)
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192
```

https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/array-functions/#arrayreduce

```sql
CREATE TABLE user_tag_bitmap_local
(
    `tag` String,
    `tag_item` String,
    `p_day` Date,
    `origin_user` UInt64,
    `users` AggregateFunction(min, UInt64) MATERIALIZED arrayReduce('minState', [origin_user])
)
ENGINE = AggregatingMergeTree
PARTITION BY toYYYYMMDD(p_day)
ORDER BY (tag, tag_item)
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192
```